# Using OpenAPI operation filters to add security requirements to controller endpoints that require authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, openapi

I am trying to improve my projects openapi definition by adding security requirements to endpoints that require authentication.

An endpoint requires authentication if it is a method of a class with the `[Authorize]` decorator, and lacks a `[AllowAnonymous]` decorator.

I am trying to use `IOperationFilter` to add security requirements based on this, but i am struggling with filter descriptors - I am not able to find any documentation on how these work whatsoever.

This is my current filter that i based on another StackOverflow thread:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization; 
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger; 
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen; 

using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OpenData.Filters {
    public class AddAuthHeaderOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

        public AddAuthHeaderOperationFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var filterDescriptor = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors;
            var isAuthorized = filterDescriptor.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is AuthorizeFilter);
            var allowAnonymous = filterDescriptor.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is IAllowAnonymousFilter);

            if (/*isAuthorized && */!allowAnonymous)
            {
                operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorized" });
                operation.Responses.Add("403", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Forbidden" });
                //Add JWT bearer type
                operation.Security.Add(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                            Scheme = "Bearer",
                            Name = "Bearer",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,

                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the `filterDescriptor` part. How do i use this to detect if what i am currently applying is a method of a class with an `[Authorize]` decorator, if it is, if it has a `[AllowAnonymous]` decorator? I might be misusing terms as well, it is a method like this i want to detect:

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("/api/[controller]")]
    public class CommentController : Controller
    {

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("metadata/{metadataUuid}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCommentsForMetadataAsync(Guid metadataUuid)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Researching this has been a pain, there doesn't seem to be any easily available documentation for this API on the web, and i haven't been able to find any examples for this version of dotnetcore/swagger either.

My versions:

- .netcore 3.1
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0

Answer (score 2):

> a method of a class with an [Authorize] decorator,if it (a action) has a [AllowAnonymous] decorator? I might be misusing terms as well

To achieve above requirement, you can try the following code snippet:

```
public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
{
    var authAttributes = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
        .Union(context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
        .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>();

    var allowAnonymousAttributes = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
        .Union(context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
        .OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>();


    if (authAttributes.Any() && !allowAnonymousAttributes.Any())
    {
        operation.Responses.Add("401", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorized" });
        operation.Responses.Add("403", new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Forbidden" });
    }
        //...

}
```

For more information about operation filters, please check this documentation:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#operation-filters